# Application context invalid in maven test

Tags: java, spring, maven-2

Upon running 'mvn test' I get the following error(s):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext ...
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: **Line 14** in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] **is invalid**; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: **Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.**

I've pasted my app context @ http://pastebin.com/24fKpgGr. Line 14, which is highlighted, seems fine; anyone see what is possibly wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `t` in `http`:

```
xmlns:xsi="htp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```